# Is it possible to achieve the following result in alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

```
<html>

<head>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div x-data="{ date1: '2023-03-14', date2: '2023-03-14' }">
        date1: <input type="date" x-model="date1">
        <br><br>
        date2: <input type="date" x-model="date2" :min="date1">
        <br><br>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have two date form fields. I would need, if date1 is greater than date2, to make date2 equal to date1. Is it possible to achieve something like this in alpine.js at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! You can put this logic into `date1` field's `@change` event listener as `if (date1 > date2) date2 = date1`.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ date1: '2023-03-14', date2: '2023-03-14' }">
    Date #1: <input type="date" x-model="date1" @change="if (date1 > date2) date2 = date1">
    <br><br>
    Date #2: <input type="date" x-model="date2" :min="date1">
    <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it really that easy? I tried it in VUE, SVELTE I could do it there, but in this particular case I had to use alpine.js and I didn't know how to proceed.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yes, Alpine.js uses the same syntax here as in Vue.js. Under the hood Alpine.js actually uses [Vue.js' reactivity engine](https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/reactivity), so they are behaving similarly.

Comment: In VUE I used computed properties, in SVELTE I used $:.
But your solution is much simpler and more straightforward.
As far as javascript is concerned I am a complete beginner, I can see that I have a lot to learn in the future.
Thanks again for your help.